# Common code for branches of an if-else-if ladder

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, goto, code-duplication

Is there a standard structured programming pattern for avoiding repetition in cases like the following (illustrated in C)?

```c
if(/* … */)      process(foo,bar,baz,0);
else if(/* … */) process(foo,bar,baz,2);
else if(/* … */) process(foo,bar,baz,5);
/* else don’t process() */
```

Storing the varying value in a variable and making the call later is the obvious approach, but requires skipping the call in the final case, which can be accomplished in several clumsy fashions:

## Extra flag variable

```c
int arg;
bool go=true;
if(/* … */)      arg=0;
else if(/* … */) arg=2;
else if(/* … */) arg=5;
else go=false;
if(go) process(foo,bar,baz,arg);
```

## Invalid value *(if one exists)*

```c
int arg=-1;
if(/* … */)      arg=0;
else if(/* … */) arg=2;
else if(/* … */) arg=5;
if(arg>=0) process(foo,bar,baz,arg);
```

## Meaningless loop

```c
do {
  int arg;
  if(/* … */)      arg=0;
  else if(/* … */) arg=2;
  else if(/* … */) arg=5;
  else break;
  if(go) process(foo,bar,baz,arg);
} while(false);
```

## Redundant test

```c
int arg;
if(/* … */)      arg=0;
else if(/* … */) arg=2;
else if(/* … */) arg=5;
if(/* … */ || /* … */ || /* … */)
  process(foo,bar,baz,arg);
```

## Unspeakable evil

```c
int arg;
if(/* … */)      arg=0;
else if(/* … */) arg=2;
else if(/* … */) arg=5;
else goto skip;
process(foo,bar,baz,arg);
skip:;
```

Is there a better, broadly-applicable option?  Python’s `else` on loops comes to mind, but can’t very well be put on an `if`!  (Python also addresses this particular case with `functools.partial`, but that doesn’t apply to statements.)

Comment: *"that doesn’t apply to statements"* — You can always make that a function… `bound = lambda x: process(foo, bar, baz, x)`… In general, that would be a solution applicable to many languages in some form or another.

Comment: @deceze: True, although it has to be a named function to have *statements*.  I’m hoping for a more generic/natural control-flow-based solution, since it’s a control-flow problem.

Comment: There aren't *that* many options, really. Either make your statement reusable (= function), or compose your conditions so you don't need to repeat the statement. The "invalid value" approach would make the most sense to me; you can usually default to `None`, `null` or an actual sentinel value as the base case.

Comment: @GuyCoder: I don’t remember much of the little Prolog I once knew, but that looks like a kind of optimization.  If so, how does it affect the *meaning* of the code in a useful way?